# How to get Form properties(form.submitted) from FormControl?

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms, angular-validation

I have created a common component for showing form validation error messages. Like below:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-err-msg',
  template: `<div class="input-error" *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./err-msg.component.css']
})
export class ErrMsgComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() control: FormControl;
  @Input() fieldName: FormControl;
  isInvalidMsg = ' is invalid';

  constructor() { }

  get errorMessage() {
    for (const propertyName in this.control.errors) {
      if (this.control.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && this.control.touched) {
        return this.getValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName, this.control.errors[propertyName]);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  getValidatorErrorMessage(validatorName: string, validatorValue?: any) {
    const config = {
      'required': this.fieldName + ' is required',
      'appPhoneValidate': this.fieldName + this.isInvalidMsg,
      'appEmailValidate': this.fieldName + this.isInvalidMsg,
      'appPasswordValidate': this.fieldName + ' must containt 8 characters, capital letters, lowercase, numbers and special character.',
      'minlength': `minnimum length ${validatorValue.requiredLength}`,
      'min': `minumum value ${validatorValue.min}`,
      'max': `maximum value ${validatorValue.max}`,
      'matchPassword': this.fieldName + ' is mismatched',
      'appEqualvalidate': this.fieldName + ' is mismatched',
      'appWebValidate': this.fieldName + this.isInvalidMsg,
      'appTimeCheckValidate': this.fieldName + this.isInvalidMsg,
    };

    return config[validatorName];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And I've used this component as:

```
<select
  name="timezone"
  id="timezoneList"
  #timezone="ngModel"
  class="form-control text-black"
  [(ngModel)]="caseDetail.timezoneId"
  required
>
  <option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Select Timezone</option>
  <option [ngValue]="timezone?.id" *ngFor="let timezone of timezoneList">{{ timezone?.timezoneWithOffset }}</option>
</select>
<app-err-msg [control]="timezone" fieldName="Timezone"></app-err-msg>
```

Here I get issue that when I click Cancel button in form, the validation error is displayed for first click and when I click second time Cancel button, form submission is cancelled. This is because I've used : `this.control.touched`.

To resolve this, I can do `if(form.submitted === true)`, but question is how can I get Form properties from just an individual FormControl as I'm just passing control reference and not the Form reference.
Is there any way I can get properties of parent form of the control?

Comment: You want to access parent form inside app-err-msg component?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you forget give type='button' in your cancel

```
<button type='button' (click)="....">Cancel</button>
```

Any way, if you use [control]="timezone", control is not a FormControl, is a NgControl

```
@Input() control: NgControl;
```

You can access to the form using

```
this.control.control.parent
```

But there're NOT a property 'submitted" in a Form

Comment: True, however, when I console.log, it does show inside control._parent.submitted: true, but when I try to access _parent in component.ts, it shows undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use the submitted property, then you can use the [NgForm](https://angular.io/guide/forms#the-ngform-directive) [directive](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#description)

Here's an example. We have a component which holds the form:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="fg" (submit)="onSubmit()" #personForm="ngForm">
      <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="name" /> <br />
      <input type="text" formControlName="email" placeholder="email" />
      <form-status
        controlName="email"
        [submitted]="personForm.submitted"
      ></form-status>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public fg: FormGroup;

  // @ViewChild("personForm", { static: true }) private personForm: NgForm;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fg = this.fb.group({
      name: [""],
      email: [""]
    });
  }

  public onSubmit() {
    // console.log("submitted", this.personForm.submitted);
  }
}
```

We have a component which displays the status of the form:

```
@Component({
  selector: "form-status",
  template: `
    <h2>form submitted: {{ submitted }}</h2>
  `
})
export class FormStatusComponent {
  @Input() public submitted = false;
}
```

We use the @Input decorator to get the submitted value from the parent.

Comment: I also agree with @Eliseo answer - you can give your button a type.

Comment: I can do by using Form, but the issue is, I have common component for showing validation message where I can't access form.

Comment: @FaizanSaiyed would you be able to share some additional code so I can fully understand what you mean? From your original post, you're using a select element which I thought would be nested inside a form.